# Singleton in MVP GWT project

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

I'm wondering should i use Singleton for my presenters? 
What is the benefit of it?

I have a weird behavior in my simple project, i have a form which is used to add new records in db and display in a table, so after the first add "click" it works ok, but in the next second or third "click" then it comes weird. For example on the second click the event is called twice and the input is inserted twice in db, if you do third click the input will be inserted three time in db, why this happen?

Thanks

Edit
So far my presenters and views are Singleton , also EventBus and PlaceManager.

Comment: Thats 2 questions. On the second one, check your code after onClick. You are rebinding the onClickHandler after the onClickHandler without dropping the first one somewhere. If thats part of your Singleton, maybe that will answer the first question too.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing presenters as a singletons can reduce testability of your code.

Consider using a [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). [Gin](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) works perfectly with GWT apps.

Answer (score 1):

totaly difficult to answer that without seeing the code, maybe you can post  the methods which are called after pressing the button?